# Catch optimistick lock exception hibernate spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

i'm trying to intercept an optimistick lock exception and throw another exception but it doesn't work in my case, the exception is catched but i still have error optimistick lock in my console.

//MY DAO

```
  public Entity getEntitieSimple(...) throws CustomException{
    
        Entity entity="my select";
    }
```

//MY SERVICE

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public Entity recupererEntity() throws CustomException{
    Entity entity =null;
    try {
         entity =   dao.getEntitieSimple(...);
    }catch (Exception exec){
        throw new CustomException("custom message");
    }
    return entity;
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void myUpdate() throws HibernateException{
    try {
    // entity update here
    }catch (HibernateException exec){
        log.error("OPTIMISTIC: "+ exec.getMessage());
        throw new HibernateException("optimi  update");
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error evern after catching the exception:

```
ERROR - 29-09-2022 09:59:44.204 - http-nio-8090-exec-5 - 3933807 -  null - c:96e7d7ca8f7d5637 - org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.apicil.cosy.dop.domain.impl.Entity#1420]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch `ConcurrencyFailureException`

```java
    private void updateStatus(UpdateOrderDto dto, OrdersStatusUpdaterService self) {
        try {
            updateStatusHelper(dto, self);
        } catch (ConcurrencyFailureException ex) {
            log.error("Concurrent modification error. Will try next time. orderId={}", dto.getId(), ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hello v.ladynev. i tried it it works in the select part but not in the update, in the update i still have error optmitick lock in my console. the Concurency after update doesn't work even if its thrown at that moment

Comment: is it the correct treatment first, should i catch the exception in the select method and update method, i think my optimistic can be throw in both but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Abdel You should catch the exception in `update()` method only. Also keep in mind. that if you update entity using JPQL, there is not `ConcurrencyFailureException`. The code I have posted is from a real system and it works.

Comment: thank you but in my case the exception is thrown on the select. i'm using queryDsl maybe thats why because in my update it doesn't thow the exception

Comment: @Abdel It can be on select. For example, you have changed a few managed entities without `flush()`. Hibernate does automatic `flush()` before select and the exception is thrown. Try to do `flush()` before select. Also QueryDSL can use a different exception for concurrent access, not `ConcurrencyFailureException`.

Comment: well in the same transaction, i'm selecting, doing some stuff then updating. the optimistick is always thrown at my select level. never in my update even without using querydsl. also the concurrency is working also with queryDSL

Comment: @Abdel enable SQL logs and see what happens

Comment: well i'm having the optimistick after update in sql log but in my code the exception is been catched on my select. i'm really really confused

Comment: what u mean by using JPQL the concurrencyFailureException, are u mean in jpql to catch catch optimistick lock  i should use another exception ?

Comment: @Abdel because Hibernate does `flush()` before select, data is not saved in the database, when you do `update()`, just cached; JPQL doesn't do any optimistic locking, you can simulate part of optimistic locking doing `version = version + 1` in the   JPQL update.

Comment: thank you for your response @v.ladynev. thats right, the flush is been doing before the select thats why. thank you for your help. also concurrency works also with queryDsl to catch optimistic locking. thank u

Comment: @Abdel Always ready to help :)